# Which protocols are used for network share access

Tags: windows, filesystems, network-shares, protocol, network-protocols

I want to figure out how to audit file access on Windows using network share access.

I have 2 computers that run Window 8 and that are not in joined in an active directory domain. Computer 1 has shared a folder with Everyone. Computer 2 copies files from Computer 1 from the shared folder.

[image]

**Problem:** I would have expected to see IO read events on computer 1 (using [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) but that doesn't happen. I know I can get IO metadata by turning [file access monitoring](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/08/26/auditing-file-access-on-file-servers/), however, that seem inefficient and difficult to aggregate with data that I receive from a minifilter file system driver (think of procmon file reads)

**Questions:**

- What protocols are used on Computer 1 and 2 to access files via network shares?
- Why doesn't procmon see IO events on Computer 1, when Computer 2 access its shared folder?

Comment: Well, the protocol is SMB or CIFS. But I would expect IO on the remote machine when actually copying files as well.

Comment: accessing the share will not cause any real IO, but copying files from the share will cause READ operations. be sure to copy a large file so it takes long enough that you will see the IO.

Comment: @GiantTree Right so SMB/CIFS, that's good to know. I can monitor Computer1, but I cannot monitor Computer 2. How dows SMB/CIFS access filesystem without going through the filesystem driver stack? I don't understand how it can read replicated/encrypted data and get scanned for viruses without going through a file system stack.

Comment: @oleksii: ProcMon doesn't show what goes through the filesystem driver stack; it only shows what kernel calls are made by _userspace processes_. Although LanmanServer seems to live within svchost.exe, I believe part of it might be implemented entirely in the kernel itself (and therefore not part of any visible process except the "System" process).

Comment: @FrankThomas I've not seen any read IO on Computer 1 (coping files of 100 MB)

Comment: Note that SMB runs from the System process (PID 4) so it may be more difficult to read its operations via procmon.  you can confirm this with ` netstat -abno | findstr LISTENING` and looking at port TCP/139 and TCP/445, which you will see is owned by PID 4.

Comment: @FrankThomas confirmed, ports 139 and 445 are in LISTENING state and are used by System (pid 4).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What protocols are used on Computer 1 and 2 to access files via network shares?

The Windows file sharing protocol is called SMB, once upon a time short for "Server Message Block". It may run over a "NetBIOS Session" layer (TCP port 139), but more commonly used over raw TCP (port 445).

(Version 1 was also often called "CIFS", although to my knowledge the standards-defined CIFS is not 100% identical to Windows SMBv1.)

On Windows, the SMB server runs as the `LanmanServer` service, inside one of the *svchost.exe* processes. (I'm not entirely sure, but I *think* part of it might be a kernel driver as well, which wouldn't show up in ProcMon due to not making any system calls at the level ProcMon is watching them.)

Comment: Good to know about the first part. Very useful, thank you. Regarding procmon - it uses a minifilter file system driver, similar to [passthough](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/passThrough) so it catches IO events metadata in the kernel, and it *should* get this data, but it doesn't. There must be some Windows API calls that either don't go through the default IO stack, or these API calls aren't registered to be filtered by procmon driver..

Comment: windows also supports the WebDAV protocol for sharing folders btw. (at least it was in use back in the Windows XP days, i also recall using it on Windows 7, but never tried it with Windows 10)